# Failure in the attempt to get WinRT Toolkit Data Visualization tools to the Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, nuget-package, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I installed WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.dll using Nuget packages in a blank Windows Phone App but when I tried to open the tools of the dll using toolbox I get the following error. (happens when I browse and select the dll)

"There are no components (in the particular dll) that can be placed in the toolbox."

Does that mean the dll has not been properly installed? Or what is the solution for using the tools of this dll?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the toolkit controls don't support the design view. You need to use the XAML editor instead. The visual tree debugger might be your best bet at tuning the design once you have the controls added to the visual tree.

Comment: I am extremely new to this area of knowledge so can you kind of elaborate more on how to perform these tasks briefly may be in a step wise explanation?

Comment: I would be really grateful for the help. I had been searching inside out for dlls which provide this functionality and managed to  find out them but still I am struggling to find out resources which provide a detailed elaboration on how to utilize these dlls.

Comment: Sure, open your XAML file and click the XAML tab that should be underneath your page design view. You can check the sample implementation here - http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample.WindowsPhone/Views/Controls/ChartTestView.xaml